# Add a feature that allows the user to divide their bookmarks into different groups

Tags: feature-request, tags, bookmarks, filtering

Whenever I find an interesting question that contains useful information I like to bookmark it. Right now I have bookmarked 567 Stack Overflow questions that cover a wide range of different subjects such as Angular, Spring, Python, MySQL, etc.

If I would want to quickly look up something about Spring in these bookmarks, I'd have to sift through the whole list first to find all the question bookmarks relating to spring.

It would be nice if the bookmarks could be filtered by tag. Next to that it would also be nice if the user could also create his or her own bookmark group which the user could give a certain name. For instance, the user could create a bookmark group for all the bookmarks relating to Python and Django. With these groups a user could search through the bookmarks much more efficiently.

Comment: For now you can use the search function, something like `inbookmarks:mine [tag]` where tag is the tag you want or multiple tags `inbookmarks:mine [tag1] [tag2]`.